# Clarifications on bubble sorting in Java

Tags: java, loops, bubble-sort

```
public void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
     int n = array.length;
     boolean madeSwap = true;// I don't understand the purpose of boolean
     while(madeSwap) {
           madeSwap = false;
           //Scanning           
           for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[j+1] ) {
                     //Swapping                     
                     int temp = array[j];
                     array[j] = array[j+1];
                     array[j+1] = temp;
                     madeSwap = true;//
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Hello, I've be given this code for bubbleSort in my class. I don't really understand what does the boolean exactly do in this context. Can someone clarify it for me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Suggestion: sit with a piece of paper and run the algorithm with an array with the values 2, 10, 7, 5 .

Comment: Try to remove it, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Guys, enough downvotes, you already shown your disapproval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the `madeSwap` flag remains `true` (i.e. the `if` statement was executed), then it means that the array isn't sorted yet.

When that flag remains `false`, it means that the array has been sorted (i.e. no sorting needed).

You could even rename it to `needsSorting`, would be much clearer.

```
while (needsSorting) // <-- Loop 1
{
    needsSorting = false; // Neah 

    // Go through the items in the array, and see if there are any suspicions
    for (...) // <-- Loop 2
    {
        // Do I still need to go over the loop again?
        if (successive elements are not in order)
        {
            // Switch elements here
            ...
            needsSorting = true; // Yep, make another pass over the array
        }
    }
}
```

If you still don't get it, watch a visual representation of the bubble sort, or go step by step with your code and watch your array values + their order.

Answer (score 2):

The boolean `madeSwap` exists as a sort of gatekeeper for the logic. Once a swap has been made successfully, the value is switched to true. As soon as the while loop is ready to re-evaluate that variable to determine if it should continue, it will check that. Since it gets reset on each loop (to false), if the entire array is checked and **no changes have been made**, that value will remain false and kick out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

`madeSwap` is for the `while loop`, as soon as it is `false` after one run of the `loop`, it stops. So as long as the order inside of the `array` is not in a `descending order`, the `loop` will continue sorting the array.

Answer (score 0):

Bad question for this forum, but the boolean checks to see if the list is already sorted. If you haven't made any swaps then the list is sorted and you don't have to reenter the while loop.

Comment: meh, I guess. I'd actually put it between a Q&A site and a forum (mostly because most Q&A sites don't allow conversations like on here).

Comment: @EmbattledSwag - [`Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers`](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: First time I see somebody downvoted for using the word "forum".